# ProtonVPN but how do I connect between local machines?

Tags: networking, openvpn

So I have two machines and they are both on ProtonVPN which uses OpenVpn and *.ovpn files. So the server is not on my local net but the clients are. What modifications can I make to either my network configuration or the *.ovpn files to exclude `192.168.*.*` addresses from the VPN connections? Note that one of the machines has an unused Ethernet port, if we need that.

Comment: the question is not really clear to me. You want your clients traffic that is supposed for your local network not to be routed thru your ProtonVPN server? Normaly packets that are addressed to a machine in your local network should automatically be routed locally. If thats not the case you could create your own routing rules for those packets.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I have this figured out. You need to create a route map for your local machines.

Comment: Clarification: I want any traffic leaving the local net to be on the VPN... but not local traffic.